# Finding parity eigenvalues from a character table

Tags: group-theory, topological-insulators, topological-phase

The all-electron code Wien2K will optionally calculate the character tables for a specified list of $k$-points. I'd like to know the parity eigenvalue for a given $k$-point and band index. Is there some way to compute the parity eigenvalue from the irreducible representation of the group given that $\{i\}$ is a symmetry class?  This would be handy to compute the value of $Z_2$.